# PyInstaller Issue with Application File Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, pyinstaller

I am trying to use PyInstaller for generating an .Exe from a Python 2.7 file. In the CMD window, I run `pyinstaller myfile.py`.

It creates a build and dist folder both of which have a number of files, including an Application file. When I click both application files, a CMD box pops up and very quickly disappears, despite my file requiring inputs from the user.

What I am missing here? Which file can I distribute to be a usable copy?

Answer (score 1):

By default, PyInstaller generates a one-folder bundle containing an executable, it also creates this executable with a console window for standard input/output. I'm just guessing, but your script don't have a GUI, right?

In any case, the better way to work is creating a one-file bundle:

`pyinstaller -F myfile.py`

In this way, you only have to execute one file.

if after executing the application, it behaves in the same way, I would say that adding the `-d` option will help you to find out what is going wrong with your generated executable. Also, running your application from a per-existing CMD window is recommendable since these windows do not close itself after running your application.

Comment: I did this but am getting the following error: `Error loading Python DLL: somepath\python27.dll (error193)` I have read that I need a 64 bit build of Python but when I install that from SourceForce, it won't run the pyinstaller command saying I need PyWin32.

Comment: download and install [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) then!

Comment: pywin32 is giving me the DLL error. When I switch to 64 bit build I get the message that I need PyWin32. My understanding is pywin is always 32 bit but just has a 64 bit build. What do I do as neither version works?

Comment: You are just confusing yourself. a 32 bit application or library can work with a 64 bit application or library. If you install a PyWin32 64 bit build in your Python of 32 bits (if you have any), it wouldn't work. You shouldn't get any error message if you installed everything correctly.

I would recommend you to uninstall both Python and PyWin32 and start again from scratch.